(q/kdb+) Looping through the take operator causing type error
List of indexes
q)iTT
1 2 3 4 1

List of data
q)data
"data1"
"data2"
"data3"
"data4"
"data5"

Take function loop
q){x#y}'[iTT;data]
'type
  [1]  {x#y}

q)type iTT
7h

q)type data
0h

For some reason I keep getting a type error when I am looping through this logic.
If I were to take the first element from each variable and run it outside the function it would work fine.
Is anyone able to explain me as to why when I loop through multiple values it is giving me this error?

Runs for me:
q)iTT:1 2 3 4 1
q)data:"data",/:string 1+til 5
q)iTT
1 2 3 4 1
q)data
"data1"
"data2"
"data3"
"data4"
"data5"
q){x#y}'[iTT;data]
,"d"
"da"
"dat"
"data"
,"d"

How did you create data ?
Are they all character arrays?
q)distinct type each data
,10h


The data comes from a table column that I loaded in from a CSV. I do some parsing on it and then run the take function to remove parts of the data. Yes, I get the same output as your distinct on mine ,10h

Why your solution does not work, I am not sure.
You can also replace {x#y}'[iTT;data] with the following
iTT#'data

It's the same thing, but fewer characters.
If you still struggle with your case here's what you can try post here the results of a type each on both variables

q)distinct type each iTT ,-7h q)distinct type each data ,10h q)

it doesn't make any sense for it not to work as per your example. I cannot replicate your error. you could try to define them in a namespace. try using \d .test and try again in the namespace see if it works. My next check would probably be the environment or maybe, if you create iTT and data programatically, they are not actually what you might think they are. A breakpoint in the {x#y} or maybe something like {(0N!x)#0N!y}'[iTT;data]
